# Mbox 2 mini and mac mavericks (mac osx 10.9) not working properly

Tags: software, mac, pro-tools

I managed to get *Protools 8.05* working on Mavericks.
I installed protools first then, **Mbox_2_USB_10_3_3_Driver_79050-2**
Its the driver for *Protools 10*.
To get play back through the headphones go to playback engine and crank the buffer to **2048**. I tried the other buffers **->1048** is scratchy
and anything under this there no audio whatsoever.

Does anyone know how to get buffer setting under **2048** without having to revert back to the previous version of Mac OS?

Comment: Mbox 2 Mini does not work correctly -- if at all -- with Mavericks. I used it use a mini with my MacBook Pro and as soon as I upgrade it stop working. I couldn't even get sound out of it. I did a Google search and found that it's not supported in Mavericks and Avid did not and will update the drivers for it.

Comment: I did have it working though only with the buffer at 2048 on the original Maverick that was released.  This was pointless though and I have reverted back to OS 10.8.5 so that I can use my Mbox 2.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to get good buffer and full functionality of protools is to revert to Mountian Lion for now till Avid comes up with an update.  I have gone back to Mountain lion and I'm using protools 8.05.  It works great without any problems.  I also discovered that for Windows 7 64-bit Protools 8.0 works and my friend uses 8.01 and says it works well too ( I have not tested 8.01 yet but will when I have more data.

Comment: Yeah most definitely, PT 8 le works fine on windows 7 64 as I've used many times with the mbox 3rd gen no issues at all. And that's running boot camp on my mbp.. However if you check out the compatibility page for pro tools and osx you'll find that it says 10.6x was the last osx that supported  PT 8.0.5, unfortunately, and I like to use Mavericks or Yosemite. So I just use PT on windows at the mo.

Comment: http://avid.force.com/pkb/articles/en_US/compatibility/Pro-Tools-Operating-System-Compatibility-Chart